# Failed to emit precompiled header Xcode 12 MacBook M1

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I recently made a switch to MacBook M1 and I decided to setup my project but got error while building the project

> Failed to emit precompiled header
> '/path/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-fynqyqirahxbqmefkcrkvgaabddw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Project_Name-Bridging-Header-swift_1R4M1N58QJUXD-clang_34M9A5D58YO9X.pch'
> for bridging header
> '/path/Documents/Dev/Carth/navigator-ios/Project_Name-Bridging-Header.h'

I have some modules which are added via Carthage while others are added via SPM.

Also in one of my submodules which is written in Obj-c I get this import error

`#import <SideMenu/SideMenu-Swift.h>` despite having the package installed via Carthage.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem with React Native and Cocoapods. What solved it for me was changing deployment target as one of third-party libraries had bigger deployment target (iOS 11 in the Podfile) than the main project (iOS 10).

Changing both to iOS 11 worked for me